# Why am I getting a blank white screen when trying to import a class from another file using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atom-editor

So I'm brand new to the React framework, and I'm running into an issue that I am having trouble debugging.

I am trying to import a class from another component in another file in my project into my app.js. This class does nothing right now but display the text "My Projects" on the page.

When I instantiate it in the app.js using `<Projects/>` my app goes from displaying the text in the app.js (My App) to a blank white screen.

I'm expecting it to render the text "My App" then "My Projects" on the next line. What am I missing?

Here is the app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Projects from './Components/Projects';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    My App
    <Projects/>
  </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default App;
```

And here is the Projects.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Projects">
        My Projects
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

Here is the error coming from the dev console:

```
invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: Invalid tag: data:application/octet-stream;base64,aW1wb3J0IFJlYWN0LCB7IENvbXBvbmVudCB9IG…MKICAgICAgPC9kaXY+IAogICAgKTsKICB9Cn0KZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQgUHJvamVjdHM7Cg==
at invariant (invariant.js:44)
at validateDangerousTag (ReactDOMComponent.js:345)
at new ReactDOMComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:372)
at Object.createInternalComponent (ReactHostComponent.js:41)
at instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js:79)
at instantiateChild (ReactChildReconciler.js:44)
at ReactChildReconciler.js:71
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:77)
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:93)
at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js:172)
```

And here's an image of the product structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smmmf.jpg

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the developer console?

Comment: can you provide us the project structure?

Comment: the code you've shown  is working as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/j2nlop4ov Maybe problem is caused by other part of your app.

Comment: @AutomationKen Your component Projects lives in the file `Projects` but it has to live in `Projects.js`

Comment: When created the app in the CLI, I was using an old 4.x version of Node. After it finished I updated it to `use node 6`. Any chance the older node version at creation could have caused it?

Comment: @Roman Yep.. there it is. I missed explicitly declaring the extension when I created the new file. Thank you for spotting my uber dumb mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Because you saved code for `Projects` component in a file without `.js` extension, it was loaded as a text file. Since the text starts with lowercase letter `data:application...` it is treated as a custom element with invalid name, hence `Invalid tag` error.